# Using Jquery Hide List 2 in Nested Divs

Tags: jquery, list, nested, hide

Trying to use Jquery to hide List ITEM 2 nested with 6 duv tags some wothout an Ids:

1- My list is under 6 dive tags
2- It is UL list
3- Trying to display / hide  list items 2 when button is checked

```
<!--
       <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_up">
        <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_p">
        <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_rt">
        <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3347_up">
        <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3347_t">
        <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
        <ul class="rtsUL">
        <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst tab_1071">
    <a class="rtsLink rtsSelected" href="#">
        <span class="rtsOut"><span class="rtsIn">
        <span class="rtsTxt">List 1</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </a>
    </li>
        <li class="rtsLI tab_1072">
    <a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" href="#">
        <span class="rtsOut">
        <span class="rtsIn">
        <span class="rtsTxt">List 2
        </span></span></span>
    </a>
    </li>
        <li class="rtsLI rtsLast tab_1073">
    <a class="rtsLink" href="#"><span class="rtsOut">
        <span class="rtsIn"><span class="rtsTxt">List 3</span>
    </a>
    </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
-->
```

Comment: Could you make an example at jsFiddle.com so that we can better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the element by the class name.  So you could do something like this: (Assuming you are wanting to use a checkbox to hide/show):

```
        //this would be the checkbox
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkTest">

        //this would go into the $(document).ready
        $("#chkTest").change(function () {
            var checked = $("#btnTest").is(":checked")                
            if (checked == true) {
                $(".rtsLI.tab_1072").find(".rtsTxt").hide() //this will hide
            } else {
                $(".rtsLI.tab_1072").find(".rtsTxt").show() //this will show
            };
        });
```

Comment: Did not work not sure if it is the too many nested divs and spans that are causing it not to work. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange, I was able to have the List 2 span hide.  The amount of nested divs/spans will not matter. If it's part of the DOM jQuery can get at it.  It's just a matter of stepping down to the right element.  What part of the code above did not work?